# Number of rows returned by query is inconsistent

Tags: sql, select

Why does the query ...

```
SELECT *
FROM LicenseHistory a
```

return a list of 1000 rows in which the license ID 24965 only occurs on one line while the query ....

```
SELECT *
FROM LicenseHistory a
WHERE (LicenseID= 24965)
```

returns a list of 123 rows, all of which contain license 24965 (as would be expected)?

Comment: 1000 is an awfully rounded number. Are you sure that's not your DB interface app cutting off/hiding other rows? what does `select count(*) from LicenseHistory` show?

Comment: duh! it shows 7587 ... sigh

Comment: I would add your own answer to your question.  This is a useful question for when the developer doesn't realize that the DB interface app is not displaying all results.  It happens to us all from time to time...

Comment: How do you know only one row has LicenseId 24965?  I have a hard time believing you went through every row and checked...

Comment: did you try SELECT *  FROM LicenseHistory order by LicenseID

Comment: I agree with MarcB: I would bet my money on your SQL client limiting the number of displayed rows.